# Rename File without entering an file extension

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, xcode7, nsfilemanager

Xcode 7.3.1, Swift 2.2

The code I have below is renaming the file as expected. My issue is that I would like to enter the "New File Name" without an extension in the Alert text input field. Then once the user presses "Yes", the file extension "m4u" gets added to the new name and ultimately rename the file "New File Name.m4u". I do not want the user to have to deal with file extensions.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.....

```
func askToRename(row:Int) {

    let recording = self.arrayRecordings[row]
    let recordingURL = self.arrayRecordingsURL[row]

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Rename",
                                  message: "Rename Recording \(recording)?",
                                  preferredStyle: .Alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: .Default, handler: {[unowned alert] action in
        print("yes was tapped \(self.arrayRecordingsURL[row])")
        if let textFields = alert.textFields{
            let tfa = textFields as [UITextField]
            let text = tfa[0].text
            let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: text!)
            self.renameRecording(recordingURL, to: url)
        }
        }))
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "No", style: .Default, handler: {action in
        print("no was tapped")
    }))
    alert.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler({textfield in
        textfield.placeholder = "Enter a filename"
        textfield.text = "\(recordingURL.lastPathComponent!)"
    })
    self.presentViewController(alert, animated:true, completion:nil)
}


func renameRecording(from:NSURL, to:NSURL) {
    let documentsDirectory = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)[0]
    let toURL = documentsDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent(to.lastPathComponent!)

    print("renaming file \(from.absoluteString) to \(to) url \(toURL)")
    let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
    fileManager.delegate = self
    do {
        try NSFileManager.defaultManager().moveItemAtURL(from, toURL: toURL)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    } catch {
        print("error renaming recording")
    }
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        self.listRecordings()
        //            self.tableView.reloadData()
    })

}


func listRecordings() {

    let documentsDirectory = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)[0]
    do {
        let urls = try NSFileManager.defaultManager().contentsOfDirectoryAtURL(documentsDirectory, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: NSDirectoryEnumerationOptions.SkipsHiddenFiles)
        self.arrayRecordingsURL = urls.filter( { (name: NSURL) -> Bool in
            return name.lastPathComponent!.hasSuffix("m4a")
        })

    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    } catch {
        print("something went wrong listing recordings")
    }

}



extension ViewControllerFileManager: NSFileManagerDelegate {

func fileManager(fileManager: NSFileManager, shouldMoveItemAtURL srcURL: NSURL, toURL dstURL: NSURL) -> Bool {

    print("should move \(srcURL) to \(dstURL)")
    return true
}
```

}

Comment: how about add the path extension in your code. //  let text = tfa[0].text + ".m4u"

Comment: Thanks for the assistance Wei Jay, unfortunately that did not do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to implement the desired functionality by making a couple small teaks to my original code above..

In the "**askToRename**" function I modified the following lines.

**From:**

```
let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: text!)
```

**To:**

```
let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: text!).URLByAppendingPathExtension("m4a")
```

and

**From:**

```
textfield.text = "\(recordingURL.lastPathComponent!)"
```

**To:**

```
textfield.text = "\(recordingURL.URLByDeletingPathExtension!.lastPathComponent!)"
```